# Removing user permission to access to analysis services database does not work

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'd like to browse data via excel and the data source is Analysis services database. After I grant my account to Roles->Membership in AS database in SQL Server, I can connect to the AS database and browse data from excel. But when I remove my account from the 'Membership' list, I can also connect to the AS database and browse data that makes me very confused. So I guess if there's cache in AS database or I should do other actions to make the configuration into effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the SSAS roles you are probably in the admin list of the SSAS server. Here is a screenshot from Microsoft on how to edit the server admin list:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174561.aspx

You can test the SSAS role functionality via MS SQL Server Management Studio by browsing the cube and [changing the security context: http://easyroles.com/2014/02/testing-role-functionality/](http://easyroles.com/2014/02/testing-role-functionality/). This will allow you to have the 'look and feel' of the cube as if you were a user with limited access.

You should reconnect to the cube every time you change role definition to avoid weird caching issues.

Comment: And I find that the users who can login to the server where SSAS server is located are also able to access to the SSAS. So I'd like to know if these users are related to the admins of SSAS server you said above. Thanks.